# Вывод строк с нечетным количеством букв в консоль на Си

Tags: c, файлы

Есть текстовый файл, который нужно считать, и вывести только те строки, в которых нечетное количество букв. На языке Си.

```
    `#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("text.txt","r");
    if (f==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        fclose(f);
    }
int x;
    char string[100];
    char *fgets(char *string,int maxline,FILE *f);
    if (isalpha(*string))
    {
        x++;
        if (x%2==0)
        {
            printf("%c",string);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}`
```

Comment: а какая кодировка файла? Что такое буква в вашем понимании?

Comment: В даном случае англ. алфавит

Comment: Хорошо, задание понятно, делайте. Будут конкретные вопросы -- обращайтесь. У вас ведь есть уже какой-то код, который например считывает файл? Впишите его, когда появятся вопросы.

Comment: Да что вы про кодировки спрашиваете? Вы на приведенный код посмотрите...

Comment: Где считывание из файла? Где цикл с проверкой? Что это за char* fgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибок в Вашей программе много. И про кодировку спрашивают не зря. Немного подправил:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("text.txt","r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        perror("text.txt");
        return -1;
    }

    int j, x;
    char string[100];
    char *cp;

    while ( (cp = fgets(string, 100, f)) == string) {
       x = 0;
       for (j=0; j<strlen(string); j++) if (isalpha(string[j])) x++;
       if (x%2==0) printf("%s",string);
    }

    fclose(f);

}
```